# MacPorts does not install package

Tags: macos, mac, package-management, macports

I installed MacPorts and XCode, then went to a terminal and issued the command "sudo port install lua" and it appears to do nothing. When i execute "sudo port installed" i get back "No ports are installed.". Why is this package not installing and what can i do to get it installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

`sudo port -v selfupdate`

which should update the local portlist and give you verbose output so you can better see what's going on.

`sudo port -v list lua` should show you the `lua` portfile if it is properly installed. If you can see it, try the install again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You probably won't believe this but the first command does nothing.

Comment: Also, i downloaded Porticus and it tried to run the "port repair privileges: command, and it gave the following error:
"Error: failed to repair privileges for path /Volumes/Porticus/Porticus.app/Contents/Resources/PortRunner (Read-only file system)"

Comment: @RCIX Try "sudo port -d selfupdate" (Reference: http://guide.macports.org/#using.port.selfupdate )

Comment: :S it also does absolutely nothing...

Comment: @RCIX - If `sudo port -v selfupdate` does nothing at all, then your MacPorts installation is seriously broken. Try reinstalling it from scratch.

Comment: I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use MacPorts, so I'm speculating, but from skimming the [MacPorts Guide](http://guide.macports.org), it seems that you might want to try issuing the command

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

and then try

```
sudo port install lua
```

again.  I assume this is a continuation of your "[Programming in Lua for the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236879/programming-in-lua-for-the-mac)" question on Stack Overflow, so you might also want to look at micmoo's most recent comment on [his MacPorts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236879/programming-in-lua-for-the-mac/1237024#1237024), although I think your PATH is configured correctly since `sudo port installed` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `-t` (trace) option:

```
sudo port -t install lua
```

The [trace option](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.html) isolates MacPorts from other software that might be active.

If that works, it means you probably have other package manager, such as Homebrew, or Fink, or some manual installation, that it is interfering.

Answer (score -1):

I use [Porticus](http://porticus.alittledrop.com/) which is a front end gui for MacPorts, you might want to give it a try. It makes installation and uninstallation a breeze.

Comment: He explained in notes to adamvs that Porticus did not help

Comment: Well, he stated that after I posted my answer.